# Watson Speech Android SDK shows INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABI

Tags: android, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

I encountered INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABI error when running [Watson Speech Android SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk) on Android Studio Emulator (Win10) but works when deployed on actual mobile device.

```
 Device connected: emulator-5554
 Device is ready: Nexus_API_21_x86 [emulator-5554]
 Target device: Nexus_API_21_x86 [emulator-5554]
 Installing APK: D:\DEV\Android\speech-android-sdk\examples\build\outputs\apk\examples-debug.apk
 Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples
 Installing com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples
 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples"
     pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples
 Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]
 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.examples
 DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Is there a way to run it on the emulator? I'm guessing it is because the SDK only provide armeabi but not x86 - but I could not verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [jniLibs](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk/tree/master/speech-android-wrapper/src/main/jniLibs) folder of the [speech-android-sdk](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk) on GitHub there are only the native libraries for the ARM architecture, for this reason when you tried to install on an x86 emulator you receive the error `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABI`.

If you want to use it on the emulator you need to create an `armeabi-v7a` emulator instead the `x86` one.